# Function's argument being "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

When I try to call the function I created (see code below), it throws an error stating that "Jon is not defined". Why is it saying that? How is an argument for a function I'm trying to call undefined?

```
function greeting(person, hour, minutes) {
    time = ((hour+12)*1000)+minutes
    if (person = "Count Dooku") {
        console.log("I'm coming for you, Dooku!")
    }
    else {
        console.log("Good day, " + person + "! " + "It is currently" + time)
    }
}

console.log(greeting(Jon, 1, 13))
```

And the error is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Jon is not defined
    at <anonymous>         
 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
Process exited with code 1'
```

I tried fiddling around in trace playground to see if I could alter the code and get it to work, but I'm pretty certain this is the basic setup for creating and calling a function. I don't even know what I would change.

I am using VS Code if that makes any difference. I don't have much experience with it, so if it's some missing extension or something I would have no idea.

Comment: If `Jon` is meant to be a string, it needs to be wrapped in quotation marks: `console.log(greeting('Jon', 1, 13))` or `console.log(greeting("Jon", 1, 13))`. Otherwise it's interpreted as a variable.

Comment: greeting does not return anything.

Comment: Well, did you define a variable named `Jon` anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

1. try "jon" instead of jon. without quotes, it is assumed to be a variable, but there is no variable `jon` defined.
2. `if (person = "Count Dooku") {` this is not a comparison, but an assignment. You most likely wanted to compare, using `==`

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but I noticed now that if I call the function inside console.log(), it not only provides the function as I made it, but also an 'undefined' at the end. If I remove the console.log(), it works just fine. Why is it throwing that additional undefined at the end?

Comment: @Kurt You're not returning anything from that function. What did you expect?

Comment: @Unmitigated Does not adding a return and then using console.log() result in undefined? I'm new to JS but I did learn some Python and I think I'm having Python expectations in JS.

Comment: @Kurt When do you `console.log(greeting())`, you're calling `greeting`, then logging its return value. There is **no difference** between Python and JS in how this works. If you try to print the result of a function that doesn't return anything in Python, you get `None` (see example [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNQ9OKSwEICooy80o0lNIUkhNzclJTlDS5ICJABZr//wMA)).

Comment: @Unmitigated Oh, I see it now! All right, thank you so much! Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this stuff overall

Answer (score 0):

```
  function greeting(person, hour, minutes) {
   var time = ((hour+12)*1000)+minutes
     if (person = "Count Dooku") {
      console.log("I'm coming for you, Dooku!")
    }
    else {
    console.log("Good day, " + person + "! " + "It is currently" + 
    time)
    }
   }

  greeting('Jon', 1, 13);
```